# Uncaught TypeError: products.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
const filterProducts = products.filter(function (item) {
    return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchfilter.toLowerCase());
  });
```

i write this code and it works for a while and a few minutes later its show me this error
Uncaught TypeError: products.filter is not a function
what should i do??

Comment: Did you make any change to products?  This usually happens if you try calling the filter function on something that's not an array.

Comment: no i didnt change it!!

Comment: @fardinvahdat Can you put `console.log(typeof products);` just before the error and share the result?

Comment: Please check the type of `products`, it should be array because the filter method works only for array data type.

Comment: What does the products object look like? I would add that to your question.

Comment: i checked it and it was object.thanks i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error, console.log the value you're calling the filter method on and make sure it's a valid array.

Read the following helpful article.

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-filter-is-not-a-function